# Some HTTPS domains fail in mono

Tags: c#, ssl, mono, certificate, x509certificate

I have some HTTPS domains which Mono cannot load the content of no matter what I do.

I am compiling and running the following code on OSX 10.11.X

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Security;
using System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates;

class MainClass
{
    public static bool Validator (object sender, X509Certificate certificate, X509Chain chain,
                                      SslPolicyErrors sslPolicyErrors)
    {
        return true;
    }

    public static void Main (string[] args)
    {
        ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = Validator;
        WebRequest wr = WebRequest.Create (args [0]);
        Stream stream = wr.GetResponse ().GetResponseStream ();
        Console.WriteLine (new StreamReader (stream).ReadToEnd ());
    }
}
```

The code is compiled using the following command

```
mcs test.cs /r:System.dll /r:Mono.Security.dll
```

and hereby executed by for example calling `http s://davidwalsh.name`

```
mono tlstest.exe https://davidwalsh.name
```

and it will fail with this message even though I have made sure I am accepting whatever the certificate is

```
Unhandled Exception:
System.Net.WebException: Error: SendFailure (Error writing headers) ---> System.Net.WebException: Error writing headers ---> System.IO.IOException: The authentication or decryption has failed. ---> Mono.Security.Protocol.Tls.TlsException: The authentication or decryption has failed.
  at Mono.Security.Protocol.Tls.RecordProtocol.EndReceiveRecord (IAsyncResult asyncResult) <0x37e5fb8 + 0x000e3> in <filename unknown>:0
  at Mono.Security.Protocol.Tls.SslClientStream.SafeEndReceiveRecord (IAsyncResult ar, Boolean ignoreEmpty) <0x37e5f10 + 0x0001f> in <filename unknown>:0
  at Mono.Security.Protocol.Tls.SslClientStream.NegotiateAsyncWorker (IAsyncResult result) <0x37da130 + 0x0019b> in <filename unknown>:0
  --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
  at System.Net.WebConnection.EndWrite (System.Net.HttpWebRequest request, Boolean throwOnError, IAsyncResult result) <0x37e7408 + 0x00183> in <filename unknown>:0
  at System.Net.WebConnectionStream+<SetHeadersAsync>c__AnonStorey1.<>m__0 (IAsyncResult r) <0x37e6e50 + 0x000eb> in <filename unknown>:0
  --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
  --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
  at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.EndGetResponse (IAsyncResult asyncResult) <0x1e97358 + 0x00187> in <filename unknown>:0
  at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse () <0x1e8c208 + 0x0004c> in <filename unknown>:0
  at MainClass.Main (System.String[] args) <0x727f88 + 0x00082> in <filename unknown>:0
[ERROR] FATAL UNHANDLED EXCEPTION: System.Net.WebException: Error: SendFailure (Error writing headers) ---> System.Net.WebException: Error writing headers ---> System.IO.IOException: The authentication or decryption has failed. ---> Mono.Security.Protocol.Tls.TlsException: The authentication or decryption has failed.
  at Mono.Security.Protocol.Tls.RecordProtocol.EndReceiveRecord (IAsyncResult asyncResult) <0x37e5fb8 + 0x000e3> in <filename unknown>:0
  at Mono.Security.Protocol.Tls.SslClientStream.SafeEndReceiveRecord (IAsyncResult ar, Boolean ignoreEmpty) <0x37e5f10 + 0x0001f> in <filename unknown>:0
  at Mono.Security.Protocol.Tls.SslClientStream.NegotiateAsyncWorker (IAsyncResult result) <0x37da130 + 0x0019b> in <filename unknown>:0
  --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
  at System.Net.WebConnection.EndWrite (System.Net.HttpWebRequest request, Boolean throwOnError, IAsyncResult result) <0x37e7408 + 0x00183> in <filename unknown>:0
  at System.Net.WebConnectionStream+<SetHeadersAsync>c__AnonStorey1.<>m__0 (IAsyncResult r) <0x37e6e50 + 0x000eb> in <filename unknown>:0
  --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
  --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
  at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.EndGetResponse (IAsyncResult asyncResult) <0x1e97358 + 0x00187> in <filename unknown>:0
  at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse () <0x1e8c208 + 0x0004c> in <filename unknown>:0
  at MainClass.Main (System.String[] args) <0x727f88 + 0x00082> in <filename unknown>:0
```

**And `mozroots --import --ask-remove` doesn't help**, the exception is thrown no matter what.

I have a few other HTTPS domains which also fails:

- http s://christian.panton.org
- http s://penny-arcade.com
- http s://rigeligtsmor.dk

And I can't seem to find a pattern on why these domains fail even when I'm taking everything in.

I have looked at http://www.mono-project.com/docs/faq/security/ or http://www.mono-project.com/archived/usingtrustedrootsrespectfully/ and googled the web out of it and no hit so far.

The closest I came is this http ://stackoverflow.com/questions/9733750/mono-certificate-issue-with-https-httpwebrequest, but this is in *nix and not OSX. Similar post http ://answers.unity3d.com/questions/792342/how-to-validate-ssl-certificates-when-using-httpwe.html and http ://stackoverflow.com/questions/4926676/mono-webrequest-fails-with-https

The small program works fine on Windows and that is because Windows has all the root certificates I need.

Maybe some of you know a solution to this problem, but I have an feeling that no one knows how to fix this.

Comment: Mono version     
    Mono JIT compiler version 4.2.2 (explicit/996df3c Wed Jan 20 00:19:48 EST 2016)  
    Copyright (C) 2002-2014 Novell, Inc, Xamarin Inc and Contributors. www.mono-project.com  
        TLS:           normal  
        SIGSEGV:       altstack  
        Notification:  kqueue  
        Architecture:  x86  
        Disabled:      none  
        Misc:          softdebug  
        LLVM:          yes(3.6.0svn-mono-(detached/a173357)  
        GC:            sgen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The domains you list as failing all require [Server Name Indication (SNI)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server_Name_Indication). My guess is that you **unknown version** of Mono has no support for SNI yet. If this is the case just adding some more CA certificates will not help because this problem is unrelated to certificate validation.

According to [this bugreport](https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=11487) Mono should have support for SNI at least starting with version 3.0.10 but not in 2.x so you might check what version you are running.

Comment: Added mono version to my post as a comment

Comment: @memborg: thanks. This version of Mono should support SNI. But since the common feature of all this domains is that they break if no SNI is used I would still recommend to do a packet capture to see if the ClientHello really contains the server name extension and if this contains the expected name for the host (and not a different name or IP address). Since you don't show the code where you make the request it might also be something wrong there which makes use of SNI impossible (like using SSL 3.0)

Comment: I did provide an example source for how I am testing the domains. It is the first code block.

Comment: After some more googling I stumbled over this post: http://tirania.org/blog/archive/2015/Aug.html and in the summary it seems that I have to wait a bit more for a complete TLS stack on OSX

Comment: @memborg: you did not provide any part of the source code where it can be seen which URL/hostname you use. The hostname is the essential part with SNI, i.e. without giving the proper hostname no SNI will succeed. As for the more complete TLS stack - I'm not sure, it says nothing about SNI there.

Comment: Sorry about the late reply. And I'm you have lost me. I have trouble following what you mean by "which hostname you use"

Comment: @memborg: if the server requires SNI it is very important how you connect to it. That is connecting by IP address only or using the wrong hostname will cause errors. That's why I've asked for the code where the actual URL is used for connection.

Comment: Created a gist: https://gist.github.com/memborg/7f7ba772f2c15ecca6f1 where the url I'm trying to connect to i added.